# loadData() or loadRecords() in Extjs 4.0.7 Store

Tags: extjs4

Getting error when loading store data After ajax request returning data.

Error - TypeError: record.unjoin is not a function

Here is my code -

```
 var invStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('invoice');                            
 var rec = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
 invStore.loadData(rec);
```

Thank you

Comment: My bad i should use -
var rec = Ext.decode(response.responseText).records; 
invStore.loadData(rec);